# in SQLite shell (CLI) how to end the statement input after ^]]A?

Tags: keys

confessing, this is not ubuntu-specific, but SQLite shell-specific. Anyway, maybe one of you out there know some hint. I'm a Linux starter btw...

I'm typing with SQLite and using its shell, accidentally typing the up arrow key.
unfortunately there is no history readline functionality linked with it, and no, i can't change that. The shell input is waiting for some end line identified, but probably is in some special escaped-mode.... so my shell session is to perish by me pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>. Any other key I tried did not change a thing.

Does anyone have a hint? Can that behaviour be changed so that when pressing those "special"keys of a standard keyboard just happen to do nothing?

Answer (score 1):

if <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> is not working then you can use the command:-

```
sqlite> .exit
```

For more information use :-

```
sqlite> .help
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, [this behaviour is known and "intentional"](http://www.mail-archive.com/sqlite-users@mailinglists.sqlite.org/msg68967.html). It behaves like this because sqlite developers don't want to make sqlite dependent on readline (the library that gives the arrow functionality to the shell) because it isn't in all GNU/Linux distributions. And, therefore, they don't distribute the binary including the readline features.

In order to have a more standard sqlite shell, you will have to build sqlite from source. It isn't that difficult, simply run these commands inside a temporal directory:
`apt-get source sqlite3
cd sqlite3-*
./configure
make
sudo make install`

After that, you should be able to enter in the your own-built version just typing `sqlite3`.

More info [here](http://www.janosgyerik.com/sqlite3-shell-and-arrow-keys-in-debian/).

---

As for the "exiting command", <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> actually [pauses the program being run and sends it in background](https://askubuntu.com/questions/465829/pausing-a-long-running-program-in-the-terminal#465834). If you want to exit from sqlite shell you should use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>