# Pausing a long running program in the terminal?

Tags: gnome-terminal, execute-command

Is there a keyboard key combination that I can use to pause a program running in the terminal? In case it matters, I don't intend to run anything else inside that terminal while the program is paused. I just want to pause the program execution, and resume it later. How can I do this?

Comment: What program exactly?

Comment: @Jobin A program I wrote in C++. But I don't want to change the source code.

Comment: Do you want to resume the process after a reboot or something?

Comment: @Jobin No, I don't want to reboot. I want to resume later, but I won't reboot the system in the middle.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Press <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>.

This will suspend the process and return you to a shell. You *can* do other things now if you want or you can return to the background process by entering `%` followed by <kbd>Return</kbd>.

Note that if you're doing this to something that needs to be responsive, you're going to tank the system, but if it's just something like a `nano` instance, everything should be okay.

Comment: Is it safe to pause terminal-process?

Comment: @Pandya: Why not?

Comment: @Pandya I'm sure that depends on the process... If something is very time sensitive, it might not expect to be suspended but most things *should* be okay.

Comment: thanks this works!

Answer (score 19):

This is [bash job control](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Job-Control-Builtins.html)

Use **CTL-Z** to stop the job.

Then you can type **bg** to run it in the background, if there's only on job it does exactly that.

If you have more than one you can use **jobs** to list then and use **fg %N** and **bg %N** to the desired effect.

Example:

```
ubuntu@ip-10-170-59-120:~$ find /usr -name "*.so"
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/OpenSSL/crypto.so
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.so
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/OpenSSL/rand.so
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gi/_glib/_glib.so
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gi/_gobject/_gobject.so
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gi/_gi.so
/usr/lib/python2.7/config/libpython2.7.so
...
^Z
[1]+  Stopped                 find /usr -name 

ubuntu@ip-10-170-59-120:~$ jobs
[1]+  Stopped                 find /usr -name "*.so"

ubuntu@ip-10-170-59-120:~$ fg %1
find /usr -name "*.so"
/usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/apc.so
/usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/memcache.so
/usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/mysql.so
...
```

For anything else not attached to the TTY you can use [SIGSTOP and SIGCONT](http://major.io/2009/06/15/two-great-signals-sigstop-and-sigcont/). So for example if you think a daemon is causing problems but you don't know which one it is, you can send the pid SIGSTOP, it's like hitting pause, then check for changes, OK that's not it, and rinse and repeat until you find the problem.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Good answer! May I just add that's it's not only bash thing ? Korn shell works the same way.

Answer (score 7):

I know that this answer is a little bit late, but you can use the shortcut `Ctrl+s` to stop your programme (if you wanna may be read the output or something like this), then you can continue using the shortcut `Ctrl+q`.